# Having a checker piece go to the tile you want it to in JavaFX?

Tags: java, events, javafx, handler, eventhandler

I'm currently creating a checker type game and while I can make the tiles move up, down, etc every time you click on them, when it comes to clicking the piece then clicking the tile I'm at a loss on how to make it work.

Here are the event handlers for the pieces and the board

```
class CircleEventHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent>{
    int Crow;
    int Ccol;
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Clicked");

        Circle c = (Circle)event.getSource();
        Crow = gp.getRowIndex(c);
        Ccol = gp.getColumnIndex(c);
        System.out.println("row is " + Crow + " & col is " + Ccol);

        gp.getChildren().remove(c);


    }

}

class RectangleEventHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent>{

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

        Rectangle r = (Rectangle)event.getSource();
        int row = gp.getRowIndex(r);
        int col = gp.getColumnIndex(r);
        System.out.println("row is " + row + " & col is " + col);

        gp.add(c, row, col);


    }

}
```

Running this code will get me a null pointer exception and point me to the "gp.add(c, row, col);"  In the rectangle event handler.  I'm not sure how to get this working, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: gp.`getChildren()`.add(`c` ....   note:  `c` isn't defined in the second event.  Doesn't your IDE point these things out?

Comment: It doesn't, sadly.  I'm not sure how to get the Circle c in the CircleEventHandler to be seen by the RectangleEventHandler.

Comment: This is a good example why you shouldn't use variables to dereference static members. `gp.getColumnIndex(r)` makes you think `gp` has been dereferenced before `gp.add`, but this isn't the case, since those mehods are static. If the `gp.add` line is the topmost element in the stacktrace of the "root cause" then the only possibility is `gp` being `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could e.g. make those handler classes inner classes and save the data in the enclosing instance to make this work.

The following example only demonstrates how to recolor rectangles based on the color of a circle clicked before, but it should demonstrate how the information can be passed around.

```
public class Board {

    public Board(GridPane grid) {
        this.grid = grid;
    }

    private final GridPane grid;
    private Circle selectedCircle;

    public class CircleEventHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            // store info about circle clicked in enclosing instance
            selectedCircle = (Circle) event.getSource();
        }

    }

    public class RectangleEventHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            if (selectedCircle != null) {
                // use field of enclosing instance to retrieve color of the circle
                Rectangle r = (Rectangle) event.getSource();
                r.setFill(selectedCircle.getFill());
                selectedCircle = null;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane root = new GridPane();
    root.addRow(0, new Circle(50, Color.GREEN), new Circle(50, Color.YELLOW), new Circle(50, Color.RED));
    root.addRow(1, new Rectangle(50, 50), new Rectangle(50, 50), new Rectangle(50, 50));

    Board board = new Board(root);

    EventHandler<MouseEvent>[] handlers = new EventHandler[] {
        board.new CircleEventHandler(),
        board.new RectangleEventHandler()
    };

    for (Node n : root.getChildren()) {
        n.setOnMouseClicked(handlers[GridPane.getRowIndex(n)]);
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

As for finding the source of the NPE in your code: This is impossible without more information, since there is no information about why `gp` is null.

Comment: Thank you fabian, that helped!